# Order by multiple columns in the SELECT query

Tags: sql, oracle, select

How can i order the results in my select query to have them like this?

```
1, 1, 0
1, 2, 0
1, 3, 0
1, 1, 1
1, 2, 1
1, 3, 1
2, 1, 0
2, 2, 0
2, 1, 1
2, 2, 1
```

I tried this query but the result is not what I'm looking for:

```
select * from my_table order by col1, col2, col3
```

In which col1 represents the first number, col2 is the second one and col3 is the last number in the above example.

This query returns:

```
1, 1, 0
1, 1, 1
1, 2, 0
1, 2, 1
...
```

Thanks

Comment: Please, describe sort order in general words. Then you'll be able to translate it to SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort should be `1-3-2`, I'd say. See line #15.

```
SQL> with test (c1, c2, c3) as
  2    (select 2, 1, 0 from dual union all
  3     select 1, 3, 1 from dual union all
  4     select 1, 1, 1 from dual union all
  5     select 1, 1, 0 from dual union all
  6     select 1, 2, 0 from dual union all
  7     select 2, 2, 0 from dual union all
  8     select 2, 2, 1 from dual union all
  9     select 2, 1, 1 from dual union all
 10     select 1, 3, 0 from dual union all
 11     select 1, 2, 1 from dual
 12    )
 13  select *
 14  from test
 15  order by c1, c3, c2;

        C1         C2         C3
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          0
         1          2          0
         1          3          0
         1          1          1
         1          2          1
         1          3          1
         2          1          0
         2          2          0
         2          1          1
         2          2          1

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```